# byte array to image

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i am trying to convert a byte array into an image
here is my code:

```
Public img As BitmapImage
Public bytes As Byte()
Sub convert()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        'Dim bitmg As New BitmapImage
        'bitmg.SetSource(ms)
        img.SetSource(ms)
    End Using
End Sub
```

but when i am running the application i get this error : Null reference was unhandled
on the last line

```
img.SetSource(ms)
```

Any ideas ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code which actually gives `img` a value. Do you have

```
img = New BitmapImage
```

anywhere?

Comment: No , adding this before img.setsource(ms) i get an unspecified error